# Assigning roles and permissions Drupal 7

Tags: users

I have a hierarchy of roles which are Admin -> shop_admin -> food_manager / drink_manager / supplies_manager

So the Admin can edit the permissions of all the roles. Is there a way to allow the shop_admin to edit the permissions of drink_manager, food_manager and supplies_manager?

So basically my question is - Is there a way to give a user permission to manage other roles and permissions?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72050/role-hierarchy-and-management-of-assigned-users?rq=1 or https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226764/manage-assign-roles-to-users-other-than-administrators?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you go on `www.yoursite/admin/people/permissions#module-user` you can decide witch kind of user can edit user permissions, so in your case only admin and shop_admin.

Of course you do not want the shop_admin to edit admin permissions, and all the pages where you can edit single user permissions are forms so you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) in order to hide unwanted options or add conditions based on user role